# SQL query to group by day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by

I want to list all sales, and group the sum by day.

```
Sales (saleID INT, amount INT, created DATETIME)
```

NOTE: I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: You have to specify what database you are using, as the date functions are different in their SQL dialects.

Comment: Look here for more info on grouping by day.
http://sqlserverlearner.com/2012/group-by-day-with-examples

Answer (score 212):

if you're using SQL Server,

`dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, created))` will return the day created

for example, if the sale created on '2009-11-02 06:12:55.000',
`dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, created))` return '2009-11-02 00:00:00.000'

```
select sum(amount) as total, dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, created)) as created
from sales
group by dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, created))
```

Comment: off the top of your head, would it be more effecient to design this way or to just use DATE and group on it directly?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic that depends on the requirements.

Answer (score 166):

For SQL Server:

```
GROUP BY datepart(year, datefield), 
    datepart(month, datefield), 
    datepart(day, datefield)
```

or faster (from Q8-Coder):

```
GROUP BY dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(day, 0, created))
```

For MySQL:

```
GROUP BY year(datefield), month(datefield), day(datefield)
```

or better (from Jon Bright):

```
GROUP BY date(datefield)
```

For Oracle:

```
GROUP BY to_char(datefield, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

or faster (from IronGoofy):

```
GROUP BY trunc(created);
```

For Informix (by Jonathan Leffler):

```
GROUP BY date_column
GROUP BY EXTEND(datetime_column, YEAR TO DAY)
```

Answer (score 64):

If you're using MySQL:

```
SELECT
    DATE(created) AS saledate,
    SUM(amount)
FROM
    Sales
GROUP BY
    saledate
```

If you're using MS SQL 2008:

```
SELECT
    CAST(created AS date) AS saledate,
    SUM(amount)
FROM
    Sales
GROUP BY
    CAST(created AS date)
```

Comment: I'm afraid these examples will group by microsecond

Comment: Andomar, I just tried the MS SQL one (after a minor tweak to the syntax).  It happily groups by date here.  I don't have time to go and try MySQL too, but I use it all day in my day job and I'm more or less certain that it's going to group by date too.

Comment: @Jon Bright: My comment was before an edit. The current one is still incorrect: the date type is only supported in SQL Server 2008

Comment: Andomar, since you made me unsure, I've just been and checked the MySQL one too.  It works perfectly and groups by date.

Comment: Andomar, the edit made zero functional difference to the result, at least as concerns grouping by date or microseconds.  If only 2008 supports the date time (I haven't looked), that doesn't make the answer incorrect, it makes it only apply to MS SQL 2008.  There's a difference.

Comment: +1 @Jon Bright: Well I'll upvote this one then, since you didn't ;)

Comment: Andomar, thanks.  I've updated the answer to reflect the 2k8 requirement.  Now leaving well alone, since it turns out with the update to the question that neither of my answers are relevant :-)

Answer (score 10):

For PostgreSQL:

```
GROUP BY to_char(timestampfield, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

or using cast:

```
GROUP BY timestampfield::date
```

if you want speed, use the second option and add an index:

```
CREATE INDEX tablename_timestampfield_date_idx ON  tablename(date(timestampfield));
```

Answer (score 8):

actually this depends on what DBMS you are using but in regular SQL `convert(varchar,DateColumn,101)` will change the DATETIME format to date (one day)

so:

```
SELECT 
    sum(amount) 
FROM 
    sales 
GROUP BY 
    convert(varchar,created,101)
```

the magix number `101` is what date format it is converted to

Comment: +1 Yeah it does, what 101 means is explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 7):

If you're using SQL Server, you could add three calculated fields to your table:

```
Sales (saleID INT, amount INT, created DATETIME)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Sales
  ADD SaleYear AS YEAR(Created) PERSISTED
ALTER TABLE dbo.Sales
  ADD SaleMonth AS MONTH(Created) PERSISTED
ALTER TABLE dbo.Sales
  ADD SaleDay AS DAY(Created) PERSISTED
```

and now you could easily group by, order by etc. by day, month or year of the sale:

```
SELECT SaleDay, SUM(Amount)
FROM dbo.Sales
GROUP BY SaleDay
```

Those calculated fields will always be kept up to date (when your "Created" date changes), they're part of your table, they can be used just like regular fields, and can even be indexed (if they're "PERSISTED") - great feature that's totally underused, IMHO.

Marc

Answer (score 3):

For oracle you can

```
group by trunc(created);
```

as this truncates the created datetime to the previous midnight.

Another option is to

```
group by to_char(created, 'DD.MM.YYYY');
```

which achieves the same result, but may be slower as it requires a type conversion.

Comment: That's probably quite Oracle-specific, but quite handy. There is also a trunc(..., 'MONTH') to quickly give you the first day of the month etc.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and intuitive solution for MySQL is:

```
GROUP BY day(datefield)
```

Answer (score -6):

use linq

```
from c in Customers
group c by DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.CreateTime) into date
orderby date.Key descending
select new  
{
    Value = date.Count().ToString(),
    Name = date.Key.ToString().Substring(0, 10)
}
```