# Search record daywise

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am stuck in a query, actually I have a search box which provide start datetime and end datetime, e.g. `2015-09-18 13:00:00` to `2015-09-21 17:00:00`

I tried the query

```
select l.date, l.center_name, l.center_office, l.offline, l.online, l.category,
(select service_name from services_master where service_id =  w.services) as servicename, 
(select vendor_name from vendor_master where vendor_id = w.vendor) as  vendorname 
from lease_reports l,wan_entries w 
where l.center_id = '7' and 
w.id = l.center_id and 
l.date between $startdatetime and $endatetime
```

I am not getting the exact result, result includes all the time between these two dates. I want day wise rows with exact interval time supplied by the user

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "result includes all the time between these two dates." Could you provide examples of your current and desired output?

Comment: @jgloves when i run the query the rows returned are between  2015-09-18 13:00:00 to 2015-09-21 17:00:00
But i want the result between  2015-09-18 13:00:00  to 2015-09-18 17:00:00  each day wise till 2015-09-21

Comment: Have you tried to query for time and then group by day? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658340/sql-query-to-group-by-day

Comment: @jgloves yes i had tried that.. but still not working

Answer (score 0):

The exact syntax will depend on what database you are using (see stackoverflow.com/questions/1658340/sql-query-to-group-by-day),

but the logic/pseudocode you are looking for is as follows.

...

```
AND day(l.date) BETWEEN day($startdatetime) and day($endatetime)
AND time(l.date) BETWEEN time($startdatetime) and time($endatetime)

GROUP BY day(l.date)
```

However, it might be clearer to the end user if you queried for date and time separately.