# Group by each day

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following sql:

```
SELECT count(TableID) AS Counted, Date
              FROM Table 
                WHERE 1
                  GROUP BY DAY(Date)
```

The problem is, that I don't want it to be grouped for just every day once (1-31).
I want it to be grouped after each day in the year. I want to get my response like:

```
Counted | Date
2 | 2016-11-15
1 | 2016-11-14
3 | 2016-10-15
```

Comment: Look at [sql-query-to-group-by-day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658340/sql-query-to-group-by-day)

Comment: `GROUP BY year(datefield), month(datefield), day(datefield)` worked perfectly.
Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what you mean. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(TableID) AS Counted, Date
              FROM Table 
                WHERE 1
                  GROUP BY year(Date), month(Date), day(Date)
```

Is the answer. Thanks to @bub.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you  ;)