# Laravel Eloquent grouping by days of the week

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm currently using this

```
 Bills::select( \DB::raw('DATE(`created_at`) as `date`'),\DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon\Carbon::parse('last sunday')->startOfDay(),Carbon\Carbon::parse('next monday')->endOfDay(), ]) ->groupBy('date')->get() ;
```

but is there better Eloquent query to search within the calendar week and group the daily count by days?

Comment: Since your query is working already, then this question would be at home here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658340/sql-query-to-group-by-day

Comment: As far as I know, there really isn't a better way to do it. That being said, you could clean up your code by either creating a function in the Bills model to accomplish this or you could create variables prior to the select to house the Carbon objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have better version in eloquent

```
$day1 = Carbon::parse('last sunday')->startOfDay();
        $day2 = Carbon::parse('next monday')->endOfDay();

        $bills = Bills::whereBetween('created_at',$day1,$day2)->groupBy('created_at')->get();
        $count = $bills->count();
```

Comment: hey you can accept my answer if it has solved your problem see guidelines here in so https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers thanks

Answer (score 0):

One more thing: in your applications's database config file `config/database.php`

Then mysql array, set `strict => false` to disable MySQL's strict mode