# Avoid unuseful doble query laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a question for you!

I got my table with data structure like this:

| acktime | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-30 14:16:38 | 15.12 |
| 2021-10-30 14:20:12 | 15.14 |
| a lot of data | in the same day |
| 2021-10-31 10:16:38 | 13.16 |
| 2021-10-31 10:20:12 | 14.12 |

I have my model RawData and I create a collection instance with:

```
$mydata = rawData::select('acktime')->OrderBy('acktime', 'asc')->get();
```

Now I have to find how much days there's in and I found it in this way:

```
    foreach ($mydat as $value) {
        $ackday = Carbon::parse($value['acktime'])->format('Y-m-d');
        
        if ($tempDay != $ackday){
            Log::info('foun a new day! '.$ackday);
            $daystoreport[] = $ackday; 
            $tempDay = $ackday;
        }
    }
```

I got my $daystoreport array with the days found in the db

Now I need to take handle $mydata day per day and for the moment I did it with:

```
    $onedayData = rawData::whereDate('acktime', $daystoreport[0])
                    ->get();
```

But this make me an unuseful query cause, I have already get all data from the table before ($mydata)...

Unfortunatly I can't do something like this:

```
for(i=0;i=length of the array; i++){    
$onedayData = $mydata->whereDate('acktime', $daystoreport[i]);
..do some stuff
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not misunderstanding what you are trying to do, you could simply group your data by the day and then perform your actions on the respective collections:

```php
RawData::all()
    ->groupBy(function (RawData $item) {
        // Format the time to a day string without time and group your items by that day
        return $item->acktime->format('Y-m-d');
    })
    ->each(function (Collection $day) {
        // Do day-based stuff in here
    });
```

Optionally, you can also [group your days already in the database query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1658387/12733135)

Comment: I don't know why ->each(function (Collection $day) trow me in error:

`Argument 1 passed to App\Console\Commands\DataReport::App\Console\Commands\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Console\Commands\Collection, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\meteostation\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Traits\EnumeratesValues.php on line 234` but olso just grouped is very good for me, thank you so much!!

Comment: Check your `use` statement at the start of your file. You are importing `App\Console\Commands\Collection` instead of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. And the `->each` function expects the second type of collection - the one you are not importing. Change that use statement and the error should be gone.

Comment: now is working! I have last question for you, since I store data via python my acktime is not Carbon style so have some problem:
`local.INFO: {"acktime":"2021-10-30T21:56:45.000000Z","temperature":14.69}  
NEXT DAY 
local.INFO:{"acktime":"2021-10-30T22:01:47.000000Z","temperature":14.68}  
`
I print NEXT DAY when $day is finished but in realty there's a shift of two hours..How can I manage this?

Comment: You need to change the timezone of your date using `$item->achtime->setTimezone('UTC')->format('Y-m-d');` depending on what your server timezone vs your desired output timezone is or manually set the timezone offset => https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-timezone

Comment: okok, My "fault" I store data from python to mysql passing trow laravel api, but just today I use acktime as a `protected $dates = ['acktime'];`. Python sended data with utc0, in plus there's olso the legal to solar time shift in the middle ....what a hateful thing